# Referencing a line starting with a keyword in algorithm2e

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithm2e

I want to describe parts of an algorithm, by linking to specific lines. I found that the package `algorithm2e` is great for typesetting algorithms, and it seems it is also able to handle labels.

However, it doesn't seem to work as expected. Do I miss something in the correct syntax?

As an example, see the MWE below, with its output. First and third attempts show that the `\ref` links to the line above the one I want to label. The second attempt is correct, except it skips a line. However, I assume it is normal, since this syntax is supposed to manually number a line when automatic numbering is disabled. I just included it here for completeness.

Please note that the issue appears at least with `\For`, `\ForEach` and `\If` so I assumed it is the same for all keywords, that may of course be wrong.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm 1}
  First line \;
  \label{line1}\For{Condition}{
    Third line\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

I want to refer to line 2: \ref{line1}.

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm 2}
  First line \;
  \nl\label{line2}\For{Condition}{
    Third line\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

I want to refer to line 2: \ref{line2}.

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm 3}
  First line \;
  \nllabel{line3}\For{Condition}{
    Third line\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

I want to refer to line 2: \ref{line3}.

\end{document}
```

### Result:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick (putting the label in the condition) :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm 1}
  First line \;
  \For{\label{line} Condition}{
    Third line\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

I want to refer to line 2: \ref{line}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting... I got tricked in all these "`\nl` must start the line", and didn't notice nothing like that was said about plain `\label`s. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think if you want to refer to the line with the condition you can go

```
 \For{Condition\label{line1}}{
```